# Removing a word from our urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have the following file structure in our ftp account.

```
/index.php    
/views/account/users/index.php
/views/account/clients/index.php
/views/profile/index.php
/views/settings/index.php
....
```

Which means that the urls is as follows:

```
www.thesite.com/
www.thesite.com/views/account/users/
www.thesite.com/views/account/clients/
www.thesite.com/views/profile/
www.thesite.com/views/settings/
...
```

What we need, is to remove views from all possible variations, so that we can link to, or enter the following url in the browser's address bar.

```
 www.thesite.com/account/users/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+views/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!views/).+)$ views/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Rules in Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on



 #/foo to /views/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /views/([^/.\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /views/$1 [NC,L]

#Rewrite /foo/bar to /views/foo/bar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /views/([^/]+)/([^/.\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /views/$1/$2 [NC,
```

Comment: This way the links work, but how can I hide the /views/ part of the url ?

Comment: How do you want to hide the part of the url?

Comment: I don't want the user to see the /views/ in the address bar of his/her browser.

Comment: The page isn't redirecting properly